# "multi level" adjacent sibling selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the following html (that is generated as is, so I could only alter it with JS):

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="header">
        <h3>title 1</h3>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr class="field_value">
    <td></td>
</tr>

<tr class="field_value">
    <td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td class="header">
        <h3>title 2</h3>
    </td>
</tr>

<tr class="field_value">
    <td></td>
</tr>
....
```

I need to target either the first or last of the trs with class "field_value" of each block of them. 
I cannot use :nth-child, as the nr of rows is dynamic. I cannot use :last-child and :first-child, since they aren't first or last childs in the table.
So my only chance would be the adjacent siblings selector or using JS.

I want to select every row that directly follows a row that contains a `td.header`:

```
tr td.header + tr{
  ..
}
```

This doesn't work, probably because it would target a tr that follows td.header inside its tr? Any Ideas how to solve this?

---

**EDIT:**

figured out a way to do this (for this specific example):

```
tr:not(.field_value) + tr.field_value{
    ..
}
```

--> I target every row following a row that does not have the field_value class.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b78unpms/2/)

Comment: CSS selectors can't traverse the DOM upwards/backwards.

Comment: Not possible with CSS as there is no parent or previous sibling selector. Javascript would be required.

Comment: sometimes you can make the impossible possible by looking at things from a different perspective ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured out a way to do this by posting the question:

I can target every tr that follows a tr that does NOT have the class "field_value"

```
tr:not(.vf__field_value) + tr.vf__field_value{
    ..
}
```

Here is a fiddle of it (propably makes it a little more clear what I am looking for):

http://jsfiddle.net/b78unpms/1/

Would still be interested in other solutions..

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to understand what you are asking, I think you are asking to select the last tr element in the table that has the class .field_value if so this would work:

```
EDITED: I didnt realize it cant do classes //tr.field_value:last-of-type
```

Selecting the next child of a row that contains header is impossible in CSS, you would have to use javascript to label the parent of the .header then select that label. Using jquery:

```
$('td.header').parent().addClass('.parent-of-header')
.next().addClass('.first-field-value');
```

To label the last one before a header you can do this with jquery:

```
$('td.header').parent().addClass('.parent-of-header')
.prev().addClass('.first-field-value');
```

Comment: I think it would also select only the very last row.. therefore same problem as with :last-child

Comment: The CSS selector would still only select the last `tr` provided it also has the class `field_value`. It would not select the last `tr` among those which have that class.

Comment: Yeah whoops, I thought it would be able to do classes. I think the best solution is to either label the tr in advance or use javascript to find the <tr>

Comment: @Rolyataylor2: It's ok mate, it happens. By the way, you need not maintain *edited* details in the answer, you can remove them. In any case, SO also has version tracking :)